# slowcheetah transformation on non-web/app.config file that do not reside in application root

Tags: slowcheetah

I have a web application that has a Config folder containing several custom config files. I set up some of these custom files for SlowCheetah transformation.

But, SlowCheetah will create a config folder under the bin folder and put the transformed file there. The original untransformed config file(s) are sitting in the config folder and that is what gets deployed.

Does anyone have a 'workaround' where I can hook into SlowCheetah so that the transformed config file gets deployed to the original folder.

I don't want to do an AfterTargets=TransformAllFiles copy from the bin\config folder back to the original config folder because I do not want to overwrite the "original" untransformed file everytime I do a build.